# Drupal Views needs settings file update for 5.24

Tags: drupal-views

I upgraded a client to 5.24 and it broke Drupal Views - my various views all had broken items.  Views message was "This view has been automatically updated to fix missing relationships". However, while saving one view worked, another didn't. Not sure if the right place to alert people to this, but here goes.  Previously the client was on 5.19.4 so your situation may vary.  My answer is below

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to update the Drupal settings file with the tables listed in menu Administer/System Settings/CMS Database Integration.  There have been new & removed tables. I then cleared the Views cache, and all was well.

Comment: You need to update cms integration in drupal settings.php when you add new custom group. I doubt if it was anything to do with upgrade unless the upgrade deleted custom group and re-created it than its a serious issue because it may be possible that you might have lost data for that custom group.

Comment: The various views all looked OK after the settings files was updated so doesn't seem to be a loss of data.  I added the Views message to the question text, perhaps that helps? Whatever the fix, it's something to check, which I had missed.

Answer (score 1):

We find a 'drush cc all' or 'clear all caches' via the UI sorts these situations post-upgrade

Comment: Fair point, but not everyone uses drush. Although I need to take serious look at it.. thanks for the hint, Pete

Comment: can do via UI too